# Spawn a single object in Unity on click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, spawn, gameobject

I want to spawn a single game object either when I click on the screen. I have tried using loop but still it instantiate more than one time.
Here I have used other loop too and tried to put it in Start method too... I have followed many youtube video but couldn't get the desired output.

```
[SerializeField]
GameObject spawnObject;

void Update()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Vector3 touchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            GameObject g = Instantiate(spawnObject, (Vector2)touchPos, Quaternion.identity);
            //Debug.Log(i);
            Debug.Log(Input.mousePosition);
        }
    }
}
```

Help me out...

Comment: Why is there a single iteration loop? You might also want to consider using the function [`void OnMouseDown()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html).

Comment: Can you be more spesific about what is the behaviour you want and how does this code behaves ?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal `OnMouseDown` only is called if you lick on this specific object either being UI or having a Collider ... not what OP is asking for. OP wants to detect a click on the screen at any position - at least from what I understand

Comment: `it instantiate more than one time` you want a single object per click .. or you want a single object overall for the entire live time of your app? Also if multiple are spawned in a single click .. are there maybe multiple instances of this scrip in your scene?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal, I have tried while loop too for single iteration as I wanted to place single Object only.

Comment: @ÇağatayIŞIK I want to create a code where a user when click on the screen, only one object will be placed during the runtime. I don't want to place object every time when I click.

Comment: @derHugo I want a single object overall for the entire live time of the app. Only single object is spawning in each click, but I want only one object overall. Once an object is placed, I don't want another one to placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to limit this for the entire live time of the application

- Either simply add a flag like

  ```
  [SerializeField]
  GameObject spawnObject;

  private static bool wasSpawned;

  void Update()
  {
      if (!wasSpawned && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
      {
          Vector3 touchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
          GameObject g = Instantiate(spawnObject, (Vector2)touchPos, Quaternion.identity);
          Debug.Log(Input.mousePosition);

          wasSpawned = true;
      }
  }
  ```
- or you could as well simply deactivate/destroy this component so it isn't further executed at all which would even slightly  save some resources

  ```
  [SerializeField]
  GameObject spawnObject;

  void Update()
  {
      if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
      {
          Vector3 touchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
          GameObject g = Instantiate(spawnObject, (Vector2)touchPos, Quaternion.identity);
          Debug.Log(Input.mousePosition);

          // destroys only this component, not the entire GameObject 
          Destroy(this);
          // alternatively destroy entire GameObject
          //Destroy(gameObject);
          // alternatively only disable in case needed again later
          //enabled = false;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Tried both the code, but I was able to get the desired result with the first one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sooo, this is a real simple solution based on your current code but it should give you your desired functionality I took out the for loop because I really don't understand why that was there... Add it back if it's needed for something that you are not sharing with us; but understand it is not required for the functionality you described.

```
[SerializeField]
GameObject spawnObject;
private bool hasClicked;

void Update()
{
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !hasClicked)
        {
            Vector3 touchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            GameObject g = Instantiate(spawnObject, (Vector2)touchPos, Quaternion.identity);
            hasClicked = true;
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            hasClicked = false;
        }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't make any difference whatsoever though ... `GetMouseButtonDown` is only true for the one frame where the button went down and will anyway not be true again before `GetMouseButtonUp` was also true once

Comment: Well, what I want is when I click on the screen, single game object will be placed at that location. And if a game object is placed in the screen, a second game object shouldn't be placed.

Comment: Could have made that little clearer... Just keep it simple and use the bool: Set `hasClicked` to true, and remove the `else if` so that it never gets turned false.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help. It worked exact the way I want without the else if block.